# Date format not changed with angular-formly when locales changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have a form generated by angular-formly.
I format the date using angular date filter

```
 this.formlyFields = [
        {
            key: 'fromDate',
            type: 'datepicker',
            templateOptions: {
                    label: this.i18n.text('searchCase_FromDate'),
                type: 'text',
                    placeholder: this.i18n.text('searchCase_FromDatePlaceholder'),
                required: true,
                datepickerOptions: {
                    format: 'shortDate',
                    'show-weeks': false,
                }
            },
            expressionProperties: {
                    'templateOptions.label': '"searchCase_FromDate" | translate',
                    'templateOptions.placeholder': '"searchCase_FromDatePlaceholder" | translate'
            }
        }
 ]
```

Here is the template I'm using:

```
<input type="text"
               id="{{::id}}"
               name="{{::id}}"
               ng-model="model[options.key]"
               class="form-control"
               uib-datepicker-popup="{{to.datepickerOptions.format}}"
               is-open="datepicker.opened"
               datepicker-options="to.datepickerOptions"
               current-text="{{'datepickerCurrent' | translate}}" clear-text="{{'datepickerClear' | translate}}" close-text="{{'datepickerClose' | translate}}" />
```

When I'm on this view and change the locale the date won't be reformated.

It will if I change the locale before arriving on this page.

I'm changing the locale with angular-dynamic-locale.
It works if in a view I display like this:

```
<div>{{vm.formlyModel.fromDate | date:'shortDate'}}</div>
```

But how to have the same rresult with angular-formly ?

Thnaks for your help.

Comment: What is the `this` returning, in `this.i18n.text`?